# Change line point to triangle in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I have a line chart of which the data points are rounded, but I want it to be triangle. Is there any way to do this?

Here is my chart code:

```
var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Sales Point',
      data: salesData,
      borderColor: bdrColor,
      fill: false
    }]
  },
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set [**`pointStyle`**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/radar.html#pointstyle) property to **`triangle`** for your dataset, like so :

```
...
datasets: [{
   label: 'Sales Point',
   data: salesData,
   borderColor: bdrColor,
   fill: false,
   pointStyle: 'triangle'
}]
...
```

**ᴡᴏʀᴋɪɴɢ ᴇxᴀᴍᴘʟᴇ ⧩**

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'Sales Point',
         data: [3, 1, 4, 2, 5],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)',
         fill: false,
         pointRadius: 10,
         pointStyle: 'triangle'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      scales: {
         yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
               beginAtZero: true,
               stepSize: 1
            }
         }]
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: Is there any way to do this for the whole chart and not every dataset?